# python class Spyder

Tags: python, class, spyder

I'm trying to get a handle on classes in Python.  I'm using Python 3.5.2, and docs.python.org and two tutorials.  This is directly from the documentation: 9.3.2:

```
>>> class Complex:
...     def __init__(self, realpart, imagpart):
...         self.r = realpart
...         self.i = imagpart
... 
>>> x = Complex(3.0, -4.5)
>>> x.r, x.i
(3.0, -4.5)
```

This works fine in terminal, but when I run it in Spyder it chokes:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Mon Oct  9 20:42:32 2017

@author: davidc
"""

class ComplexNumber:
    def __init_(self,realpart, imagpart):
        self.r = realpart
        self.i = imagpart

x = ComplexNumber(3.0, -4.5)
```

I get this error:

```
x = ComplexNumber(3.0, -4.5)

TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

Question: why would it run in terminal, but not in Spyder?

Any insight would be appreciated

Comment: terminal and spyder use different python versions?

Comment: Both terminal and Spyder use Python 3.5.2.